# how to stop a process when another is running java android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, pthreads

i am doing an app in android that connecting with servers and downloading some chunks. 
now i want to have another one process doing other job. here is my code

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {


                    public void run() {

                       flag = true;
                       System.out.println(" Hello World!");
                        Receiveeterations reeterations = new Receiveeterations();
                         int longCounteterations = reeterations.Geteterations();
                         System.out.println("longCounteterations " + longCounteterations);

                       long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;

                        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {


                               } 

                        IntegerResult = 4;
                        ThroughPut1+=1;
                        ThroughPut2=0;

                        //se mia methodo! pou otan oloklirwnetai i diadikasia tha ti kanei false    
                        flag=false;   
}

 Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 0,20000);

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  


                       try {
                            Thread.sleep(10010);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                            }  
while (!fileparts.isEmpty()  ) { //&& !fileparts1.isEmpty() && (flag == false) 




    String[] myStringArray = new String[IntegerSpeed];

here i have more code with connectios

        }
```

so what i want to do and i don't know, is how when the timer class is triggered the while process will stop. and after the process of timer stops the main method continues.
i try thread.sleep inside timer but it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is a running flag... maybe that is what you have your `flag` variable for?

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    private boolean runnging = false;

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        [...]
        while (running && System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
            // work
        }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        // interrupt the thread if possible
    }
}
```

now you can call `stop()` on your running task to make it stop

Comment: Thanks Marco i solved it! yes i had the flag there but because i an new to programming i changed it to public! and after that it was ok!! thanks!!